# MQTT error after 5 minutes

Tags: react-native, mqtt, iot

I have a React-native app that I need to connect with IoT (AWS), with websockets. I currently use the package [react-native-paho-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paho-mqtt) to connect my app. Here is my code :

```
function getClient(onConnect, onConnectionFailed, onConnectionLost, 
  onMessageArrived) {
  logger.trace('getClient()');
  const clientID = uuidV4();
  // Create a client instance
  const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(signedUrl, clientID);  // eslint-disable-line no-undef

  // set callback handlers
  client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
  client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

  // connect the client
  client.connect({
    keepAliveInterval: 15,
    onSuccess: onConnect,
    onFailure: onConnectionFailed,
  });

  return client;
}
```

5 minute after my main connection, I get an error when I try to connect an other client. I get this error: `AMQJS0007E Socket error:{0}.`. I do not have any more information about the error.

Does anyone know what is happening or how to solve this problem ?

Comment: How many clients do you create? Maybe you are hitting the client limit ?

Comment: Do you have the logs from the broker you are connecting to?

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for trying to help, but I do not work on that app anymore.